# How do I find the current class in pagination of slider and add it to another section with the same number of divs?

Tags: jquery, indexing, pagination, slider, jquery-animate

Here is the HTML and the script I am trying to use. I need to addClass "current to each div and have it cycle like the pagination.

```
   <div id="slider">
        <div class="superslider"><img class="one"><img class="two"><img class="three"><img class="four">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="current" data-index="0">Item 1</li>
                <li data-index="1">Item 2</li>
                <li data-index="2">Item 3</li>
                <li data-index="3">Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="overlay" class="animations">
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>
//this is the script I am trying to make work.....    
    $("#slider ul li").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("current"))
            $("#slider .animations:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + ")").addClass("current");
    });
```

Comment: On what trigger you want to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index) to get the pagination current class element's index within it's siblings and [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to target the same index in the other elements

```js
const currIdx = $('.pagination .current').index();
$('.animations').children().eq(currIdx).addClass('current')
```

```css
.animations .current{border:3px solid green; background:yellow }
li{ display: inline}
li.current{ color:red}
[data-animation] { height: 20px; border : 1px solid #ccc; margin:10px; background :pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
        <div class="superslider"><img class="one"><img class="two"><img class="three"><img class="four">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="current" data-index="0">Item 1</li>
                <li data-index="1">Item 2</li>
                <li data-index="2">Item 3</li>
                <li data-index="3">Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="overlay" class="animations">
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
            <div data-animation="animate"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works in the basic code you supplied. I still have a problem though as I see when the slider starts up the console log shows the index of the pagination at -1 to start. It then will cycle throuh 0 to 3 and restart at 0 again. I am unsure how to address the -1 start value. I have used the code supplied in two different triggers onclick for the prev and next controls. The prev subracts one and works ok. I cannot get the next to work as it wants to start at -1 the first round. I may have to use the data-index attributes on the pagination li's if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Several ways... check length of elements vs index and do reset at each end. Or using jQuery check if `next()` or `prev()` exist and adjust accordingly